# Deleting and replacing a record from mysql after a certain date

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently implementing a website where the admin user can post an offer which can be viewed by users. The offer has an expiry date which can be selected by the admin user. I am able to insert the offer details in the database. However I want to retrieve just one offer from the database which should only be displayed until the expiry date. After the expiry date, it should remove that offer from the database and  replace it with the next one in the database.

I have a table called offers which has the following fields (**offerid,offertitle,details,expirydate**)

**addoffer.php**

```
 $title =  $_POST['offertitle'];
 $details = $_POST['details'];
 $enddate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));

 $sqlquery = "INSERT  INTO `offers` (`offerid`, `offertitle`, `details`, `expirydate`) 
VALUES ( NULL, '$title', '$details', '$date')";
  if($mysqli->query($sqlquery)){
      echo '<h3>Offer posted</h3>';
  }else { 
      echo 'error';
  }
```

**view offer.php**

```
$mysqlquery = "SELECT * FROM offers";
$results = $mysqli->query($mysqlquery);

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
   while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "". $row["offertitle"]. ""; 
   }
}
```

Any way of doing this so the webpage only displays one offer until its expiry and then replace it with the next one in the database ??

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as follow.It will display all the offer except the expire one.

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
$mysqlquery = "SELECT * FROM offers where expirydate<$current_date ";
$results = $mysqli->query($mysqlquery);

if ($results->num_rows > 0) {
   while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "". $row["offertitle"]. ""; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write simple SQL query for this:

```
SELECT * FROM offers WHERE expirydate > NOW() ORDER BY expirydate LIMIT 1
```

Assuming Your expirydate field is of type DATE or DATETIME this will work. It fetches first offer ordered by expirydate so the soon-to-be-expired offers come first.

Deletion is another issue. You can;t perform SELECT and DELETE in single query. However another query will delete expired offers:

```
DELETE FROM offers WHERE expirydate < NOW()
```

Comment: The expirydate field is  a  DATE type. Would this be able to delete the offer and replace it the next one from the table

Comment: Yes, You can use comparsion on date fields, in this case expirydate > NOW() means anything in the future. Other statement expirydate < NOW() means anything in the past.

If it's a DATE not DATETIME field then You probably would want to use CURDATE() instead of NOW() since the NOW() function gives You date and time. In this case remember to use equal-greater operator:

SELECT * FROM offers WHERE expirydate >= CURDATE() ORDER BY expirydate LIMIT 1

This means - give me something that expires today or in the future.